# Dejar marcados los checkbox correspondientes

Tags: jquery, ajax

Buenos días tengo una lista de candidatos que se pueden asociar a cierta vacante, desde el checkbox hago que valide que si ese candidato seleccionado ya esta asociado, mande un modal con ese mensaje y por tanto si selecciona otro que no lo este no mande nada. Hasta ahí todo bien solo que puse una sentencia en el cual al salir ese modal desmarque el checkbox pero lo hace incluso con los que la vacante que no tiene vinculo, es decir, si selecciono primero un candidato que no este asociado no manda el modal ni quita la palomita del checkbox (esta bien) y si elijo a su vez otro que si lo este, manda el modal (esta bien) pero me desmarca hasta el otro checkbox del candidato que no esta asociado. ¿Cómo puede hacerle para que solo quite la selección del candidato que ya esta asociado y deje los demás que no? Creo yo que debe ser en una propiedad solo que no se cual es. Y si es otra cosa este es el código:

```
$('#formDatosCandidatos').on('change','input[class="idRecurso"]',function(){
     var buttons = "";
     var table = $('#tabla').DataTable();

     buttons = table.buttons( ['.asociarVacante'] );

     var idRecurso = $(this).val();

     var idVacantes = <?= json_encode($idV,JSON_HEX_QUOT | 
                      JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS
                     ) ?>

     $.ajax({
        url: ajaxVerificaVacante2,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
          idRecurso : idRecurso,
          idVacantes  : idVacantes,
          _csrf  : _csrfToken
        },
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
          if(data.mensajes != 0){
            var Contenido ='';

            $("#texto").html(data.mensajes);

            $(".idRecurso").prop('checked', false); //AQUI ES DONDE DESHABILITO EL CHECKBOX PERO ENTIENDE QUE DESMARQUE TODOS SI SELECCIONA UNO QUE ESTE ASOCIADO

            buttons.disable();
            $('#existeEnVacante').modal('show');
          }
        },
        error: function(exception){
          console.log('error' + exception);
        }
      });

    if(this.checked==true){
        buttons.enable();
    } else {
        buttons.disable();

    }
});
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado localizar el checkbox por id y no por la clase? Ya que esta seguramente la comparten todos los checkboxes.

Comment: Ya lo acabo de hacer pero ahora solo me muestra el modal y desmarca el checkbox en caso de que el candidato asociado este al principio de la lista. Si esta en otro lugar solo muestra el modal y no quita la palomita. Buena idea pero no funciona gracias.

Comment: Espera, ¿tu pregunta es sobre desmarcar el checkbox o sobre deshabilitar ("poner gris para que no funcione")? si es el segundo caso lo que debes hacer es `$(".idRecurso").prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: Es sobre desmarcar perdón :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya tiene rato que pude solucionarlo...se me paso publicarlo por si se ocupa, el fragmento que ingrese esta comentado:

```
$('#formDatosCandidatos').on('change','input[class="idRecurso"]',function(){
     var buttons = "";
     var table = $('#tabla').DataTable();

     buttons = table.buttons( ['.asociarVacante'] );

     var idRecurso = $(this).val();

     var idVacantes = <?= json_encode($idV,JSON_HEX_QUOT | 
                      JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS
                     ) ?>

     $.ajax({
        url: ajaxVerificaVacante2,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
          idRecurso : idRecurso,
          idVacantes  : idVacantes,
          _csrf  : _csrfToken
        },
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
          if(data.mensajes != 0){
            var Contenido ='';

            $("#texto").html(data.mensajes);
            $('#existeEnVacante').modal('show');

            //Recorrer los checkbox y dependiendo lo que
            //tenga el indice (e), si es igual al correspondiente
            //id del candidato asociado a la vacante, marca
            //o desmarca el checkbox dejando los otros
            $('#formDatosCandidatos input[type=checkbox]').each(function(i,e){

              if($(e).val()==idRecurso){
                $(e).prop('checked',false);
                buttons.disable();

                $('input[class="idRecurso"]:checked').each(function() {
                  buttons.enable();
                });
              }
            });
          }
        },
        error: function(exception){
          console.log('error' + exception);
        }
      });

    if(this.checked==true){
        buttons.enable();
    } else {
        buttons.disable();

        $('input[class="idRecurso"]:checked').each(function() {
          buttons.enable();
        });
    }
});
```